# Angular js Reporting Error in chrome and mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, wcf

I am new to Angular Js . Today while Writing Code I came accross this Error 
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8090/TimeSheetLog/ValidateUser/we/we. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:55273' is therefore not allowed access.**
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaGNy.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuHTV.png[image: WebConfig Fileimage]

[image] Controller Code

In this I am trying to access WCF Service in My Controller Code As ..

Answer (score 0):

So the problem lies not in your AngularJS code, but on the server. What are you using as your web server? I see that you have asp.net tagged in your question, so if that is the case, in your handler you can put:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
}
```

That should allow you to do CORS, which is what you need.

You will also need to modify your web.config to include:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ExampleHandler" verb="*" path="ExampleHandler.ashx" type="ExampleNamespace.ExampleHandler, ExampleNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```